# Django password hashing different from python passlib pbkdf2 library

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords, pbkdf2

Using `django` admin, I have created a user

```
email: cuteemail@example.com
password: ccpass!ccpass
```

The hashed password stored in the database is

```
pbkdf2_sha256$260000$alGB1h2BRHwn83nz9fSJ3V$qippfbL8g59KPoDh+cIEh70TQCjuWeH8017VcLLpDIY=
```

All I know is that `django` is generating the password hash using `PBKDF2` algorithm.

I need to run a pure python script that inside a part of it, it checks if a password is matching a hash. I have found a library `passlib`. I can provide the password and rounds. But where does the django salt come from?

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

password = 'ccpass!ccpass'
db_hashed_password = 'pbkdf2_sha256$260000$alGB1h2BRHwn83nz9fSJ3V$qippfbL8g59KPoDh+cIEh70TQCjuWeH8017VcLLpDIY='

salt = db_hashed_password.split('$')[2].encode()
pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password, rounds=260000, salt=salt)
```

result:

```
$pbkdf2-sha256$260000$YWxHQjFoMkJSSHduODNuejlmU0ozVg$qippfbL8g59KPoDh.cIEh70TQCjuWeH8017VcLLpDIY
```

The resulted password hash apparently looks the same except minor differences.

The `pbkdf2-sha256` has a dash instead of an underscore but this is not a problem. I can fix it.

The main problem is that I do receive a `.` instead of `+` in the actual hash part. How to fix this? Can I blindly replace all `.` with `+` ?

I also do not understand why is the calculated salt different from the original salt?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the `django` source code.

Having a look at [encode function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c58a8acd413ccc992dd30afd98ed900897e1f719/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L305) and [pbkdf2 function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c58a8acd413ccc992dd30afd98ed900897e1f719/django/utils/crypto.py#L77), I can write the following code:

```
import base64
import hashlib

myhash = base64.b64encode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt, 260000, None)).decode("ascii").strip()

print("%s$%d$%s$%s" % ('pbkdf2_sha256', 260000, salt.decode(), myhash))
```

This pure python code gave me the same result as django:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$260000$alGB1h2BRHwn83nz9fSJ3V$qippfbL8g59KPoDh+cIEh70TQCjuWeH8017VcLLpDIY=
```

.